# Setting the display range suplot of errorbars in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot my data using matplot lib. I have 3 separetes sets of data I want to plot in 3 subplots (I'm using [this](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/errorbar_demo.html) is my guidence):

```
plt.figure()

fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols = 1, sharex=False)
ax1 = axs[0]
ax1.errorbar(X,Y,Err,fmt='o')
ax1.set_xscale('log')
ax1.set_yscale('log')
ax1.set_title('epsilon=1.5, kappa = 2')
plt.show()
```

However I get the x range from 1 (or 0, I'm not sure) to 100 and I want to reduce it. I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7030807/setting-an-axis-in-matplotlib), by adding using:

```
ax1.xlim(0.5,13.5)
```

But I get an error:

> AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'xlim'

How can I change the range then?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You might want to use `Axes.axis(*v, **kwargs)`:

```
ax1.axis(xmin=0.5,xmax=13.5)
```

From the documentation:

> Set/Get the axis properties
>
> If len(*v)==0, you can pass in xmin, xmax,
> ymin, ymax as kwargs selectively to alter just those limits without
> changing the others.

Answer (score 12):

The corresponding method of axis object is `set_xlim(xmin,xmax)`.