# Removing padding from Matplotlib spectrogram

Tags: matplotlib, padding, spectrogram

I'm trying to remove the white spaces padding matplotlib's generated spectrogram. I've tried setting a limit to the axis and setting tight to the axis but these don't work.

Here's a screenshot:
[image: Screenshot with padding]

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python, Matplotlib, subplot: How to set the axis range?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2849286/python-matplotlib-subplot-how-to-set-the-axis-range)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `plt.xlim()` and `plt.ylim()` with the desired limits.

Your `plt.axis(...)` should have done, try to run it after the plot.

[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7030807/setting-an-axis-in-matplotlib), and [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15858192/how-to-set-xlim-and-ylim-for-a-subplot-in-matplotlib).

Comment: I tried with those functions but they don't work. I'm using Jupyter so I thought it was a problem with

Comment: ... "%matplotlib notebook", so I changed that to "%matplotlib inline" like how they show up in examples but that doesn't work either.

Comment: Have you tried to use those commands after the `plt.specgram`? Or use the `set_autoscale_on(False)` on your axis before drawing?